# flutter build is called repeatedly

Tags: flutter

Debug the code below when I push or pop route，build is called repeatedly， **print(1)** always called and print to the console.

```
import 'package:demo/route/demo.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Home());
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Body(),
    );
  }
}

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(1);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('home'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DemoPage(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
            tabs: [
              Text(
                '1',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              Text(
                '2',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ],
            controller: _controller,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _controller,
              children: [
                ListItem(),
                ListItem(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListItemState createState() => _ListItemState();
}

class _ListItemState extends State<ListItem> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('1'),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

**DemoPage()** is a very simple page.

I try to annotate the code to find out where the problem is, when I annotate the **TabBar** and **TabBarView** Widget, and the initialization tabcontroller in initstate, the situation will not happen again. so I think the problem is tabcontroller, and I'm not sure it's right.

I want to know why this happens, is it my problem or is it normal.

Thank everyone for their help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is completely normal. You should expect the framework to rebuild the widgets at any time.

Let's say you have animation. Flutter will rebuild 60 times/sec.

Comment: Will this redundant rebuild lead to a waste of performance? I don't have data changes or animation execution.

Comment: No, it will not lead to performance issues.